# Error in Build Path of a 'basic' Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am using Spring Inializr to create a maven based hello world java project. However I keep getting this error message : `Archive for required library: '/home/user/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/snakeyaml-1.19.jar' in project 'demo' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file.`

I have tried to exclude the given dependency from spring boot starter and add it explicitly, still the problem persists.

Comment: You may have a corrupt dependency that needs to be redownloaded.

Comment: How to fix that please, I am totally new to Spring Boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a corrupt jar. Do the following:

1. Delete the dependency from the location:
   rm -rf '/home/user/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.19'
2. Do a maven->Update project or run "mvn clean install" command.

Answer (score 0):

**

> you have to download your dependencies again because you had a corrupt
>   dependency.

**